# using replace in files in visual studio with regular expression is not excluding line break

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

In visual studio on the find and replace screen I have under find what

```
   \.Text =(.+)
```

and in the replace with: I have

```
.Text = server.HtmlEncode($1)
```

unfortunately it is including page break character in its find.

so it is changing

```
txtReleaseNum.Text = oTCSnextval.nextTire_Contract_Num().PadLeft(6, "0"c)
End If
```

to

```
    txtReleaseNum.Text = server.HtmlEncode( oTCSnextval.nextTire_Contract_Num().PadLeft(6, "0"c)
)                 End If
```

I would like to change it to

```
            txtReleaseNum.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(oTCSnextval.nextTire_Contract_Num().PadLeft(6, "0"c))
```

and not run into the next line.(leave the next line in this case end if alone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try turning the singleline flag on

```
(?s:(.+))
```

**Source:** [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Or you can try this:

```
([^\r\n]+)
```

This literally means everything except carriage return (`\r`) and line feed (`\n`).

Comment: yep the \r\n worked thanks  I used \.Text =(.+)\r\n for the find and it fixed it